# Dependency injection not working custom form

Tags: forms, 8, dependency-injection

I have a custom module with a form class, where I am trying to inject a custom service to use within it's submit method:

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\my_module\CustomManager;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class CustomForm extends FormBase{

  private $custom_manager;

  function __construct(CustomManager $custom_manager) {
    $this->custom_manager = $custom_manager;
  }

  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
    // Load the service required to construct this class.
      $container->get('my_module.manager')
    );
  }

  .....

  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {          
      // Test service.
      $this->custom_manager->test();
  }

}
```

When I submit the form, I get the following error:

***Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on null***

It seems like my custom service hasn't been instantiated as expected, since the $custom_manager property is null.

Strange thing is when I debug the constructor, the service ***IS*** being instantiated properly.

Has anyone had this issue before? I can instantiate the service via the global Drupal class, but apparently doing the dependency injection is best practice.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

I **accidentally declared the $custom_manager property** of my class as ***private*** instead of ***protected***, and that's why I was unable to access the custom manager object in the form submission method. Whoops!

MPD's answer is theoretically correct though, as class requiring to access services do need to implement the **ContainerInjectionInterface** class.

Worth noting though that the class **FormBase** which we're extending, ***already implements*** **ContainerInjectionInterface**, so we don't need to explicitly do so when creating a custom form.

Comment: Yes, we had this recently in a project too. This is actually related to serialization, because the DependencySerializationTrait doesn't see your property and can therefore not restore it.

Comment: ah interesting! thanks for sharing, I wouldn't have had the first clue why the private property wasn't being assigned otherwise

Comment: I had the same issue, thank you very much! you save my day

Answer (score 3):

Not 100% sure this is the problem, but anything with dependencies needs to implement `ContainerInjectionInterface` in one way or another (directly or inherited via the parent class).  So, your problem is likely that you need to do

```
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerInjectionInterface;

class CustomForm extends FormBase implements ContainerInjectionInterface {
  // ...
}
```

That way it will be picked up via discovery by the `ClassResolver` and have the `::create()` method called.  Just make sure you do a `drush cr` (or equivalent) to make sure everything gets wired up properly.

Comment: Yes. ContainerInjectionInterface for controllers and forms, ContainerFactoryPluginInterface for plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to change the results of my issue. Further investigation it seems like FormBase (which we're extending) already implements ContainerInjectionInterface anyway.

Comment: After your answer I spotted my specific syntax error. Upvoted your answer since it's theoretically correct. Thanks again! :)